# Trying to connect to a PostgreSQL DB via "pgsql" DSN returns "ERR [unable to open database file]" on FreeSWITCH 1.8

Tags: lua, freeswitch

When I try to connect to a remote PostgreSQL server, I get

```
2019-08-23[ERR] switch_core_db.c:223 SQL ERR [unable to open database file]
```

when using the FreeSWITCH Lua API with a `pgsql` connect string:

```
conn_string =
  "pgsql://hostaddr=1.2.3.4"                 ..
  " dbname=my-db"                            ..
  " user=postgres"                           ..
  " password=postgres"                       ..
  " options='-c client_min_messages=NOTICE'" ..
  " application_name='freeswitch'"

freeswitch.Dbh(conn_string)
```

(as recommended in the [docs](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/FreeSWITCH+Databases))

This setup has been working flawlessly, even across FreeSWITCH service restarts,
then I foolishly did a `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` on Debian 9,
and that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my final frustration I resorted to re-create the entire VM with a new FreeSWITCH installation, and found a new section in the [Debian 9 Stretch install guide](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Debian+9+Stretch):

> ### 1.10 incompatible change
>
> because now Fs1.10 packages are installed even if you still use the
>   1.8 repo, you better aware of an incompatible change:
>
> `pgsql` is no more in core, but in aptly named `mod_pgsql`.
>
> You MUST NOT load `mod_pgsql` in `modules.conf.xml` (do not work), but
>   in a special additional xml file, in same "autoload_configs"
>   directory.
>
> Filename: `pre_load_modules.conf.xml`
>
> ```
> <configuration name="pre_load_modules.conf" description="Modules">
>   <modules>
>     <!-- Databases -->
>     <!-- <load module="mod_mariadb"/> -->
>     <load module="mod_pgsql"/>
>   </modules>
> </configuration>
> ```

So when I did `sudo apt upgrade`, FreeSWITCH got upgraded from 1.8 to 1.10.

---

**(2019/08/23) Update**: Updating `pre_load_modules.conf.xml` didn't work, despite the warning above. It only connected after adding `mod_pgsql` to `modules.conf.xml`.

**The full solution on Debian 9 Stretch**:

1. Add `<load module="mod_pgsql"/>` to `modules.conf.xml`.
2. `sudo systemctl stop freeswitch`
3. `sudo systemctl start freeswitch`

---

**(2019/09/03) Update and warning, from Andrey Volk, SignalWire Platform Engineer**:

**Andrey Volk**: "*Do not add `mod_pgsql` to `modules.conf.xml` unless you know what you are doing. Use `pre_load_modules.conf.xml`. And if there is any problem with that, create a Jira ticket.*"

**toraritte**: "*why would it be an issue to load `mod_pgsql` in `module.conf.xml`?*"

**Andrey Volk**: "*The difference is that the Core may want to use that database as well. But it's the Core, it loads BEFORE any module. So we need a special place where database modules (just in case one of them is for the Core) are loaded BEFORE any other module type. On the other hand it does not matter what file to use if that database module is not used by the Core. It should just go first. If it's for LUA, load it before LUA. But we don't recommend/document that.*

*If `pre_load_modules.conf.xml` is not recognized, then it's probably a result of a bad upgrade. Make sure all freeswitch packages were upgraded (including main one).*"

Comment: Do not add mod_pgsql to modules.conf.xml unless you know what you are doing. Use pre_load_modules.conf.xml And if there is any problem with that, create a Jira ticket.

Comment: I'd suggest to double check `pre_load_modules.conf.xml` file permissions and compare them to the other xml files.